# How do you write a migration to rename an ActiveRecord model and its table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-activerecord

I'm terrible at naming and realize that there are a better set of names for my models in my Rails app. 
Is there any way to use a migration to rename a model and its corresponding table?

Comment: I suggested adding "ActiveRecord" to this question to improve search engine matches. I've been looking for this using "ActiveRecord rename table".

Comment: If you are using migrations, this problem is more complicated than it seems.  The selected solution says to just go back and manually rename the model, controller, etc. after you've changed the table name.  If you do this, all older migrations that refer to your model by its older name will fail.  So when someone clones your repo and tries to run `rake db:migrate`, it will fail.  You could go back and change those names in the migration, but that will get messy. You might be better off just creating an entirely new model rather than renaming it.

Comment: @andrewhannigan:  Isn't your point moot if someone clones your repo and just runs `rake db:schema:load`?

Comment: @istrasci: absolutely. In fact, running `rake db:migrate` to set up a database from scratch is actively discouraged, exactly because of the concerns pointed out by andrew.

Comment: Run `find . -name "*<lowercase_model_name>*"` in your app's root directory to list the files you may need to rename. (But don't rename migration files.)

Answer (score 619, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
  end

  def self.down
    rename_table :new_table_name, :old_table_name
  end
end
```

I had to go and rename the model declaration file manually.

**Edit:**

In Rails 3.1 & 4, `ActiveRecord::Migration::CommandRecorder` knows how to reverse rename_table migrations, so you can do this:

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
  end 
end
```

(You still have to go through and manually rename your files.)

Comment: Yes but this doesn't change the name of the model, does it?

Comment: it changes only the table name.

Comment: Does this mean you have to rename the Controller and View folders/files manually as well? Are those all of the things to manually rename?

Comment: @mathee: yes, you have to change that manually, or using an IDE that can do Ruby refactoring and commit it to your version control system.

Comment: git grep is your friend. I'm renaming an Activity to a Habit right now: `git grep -i activit` is very revealing.

Comment: you have to also change the content of your controller, right?

Comment: And don't forget your routes.rb!

Comment: Also, just as a heads up, you want to use the plural version of your table name in the rename_table call.

Comment: Some more ideas on automating the renaming process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924124/how-to-rename-rails-controller-and-model-in-a-project/27376575#27376575

Comment: Remember that usualy the table_name is plurla

Comment: If you are new to Rails, you can open migration script with this `rails generate migration RenameOldTableToNewTable`, update the new migration file as suggested and then `rake db:migrate`. If you don't know exact name of the table do `rails console` and `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables` to list all tables

Answer (score 77):

In Rails 4 all I had to do was the def change

```
def change
  rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
end
```

And all of my indexes were taken care of for me. I did not need to manually update the indexes by removing the old ones and adding new ones.

And it works using the change for going up or down in regards to the indexes as well.

Answer (score 59):

The other answers and comments covered table renaming, file renaming, and grepping through your code.

I'd like to add a few more caveats:

Let's use a real-world example I faced today: renaming a model from 'Merchant' to 'Business.'

- Don't forget to change the names of dependent tables and models in
  the same migration. I changed my Merchant and MerchantStat models to Business and BusinessStat at the same time. Otherwise I'd have had to do way too much picking and choosing when performing search-and-replace.
- For any other models that depend on your model via foreign keys, the other tables' foreign-key column names will be derived from your original model name. So you'll also want to do some rename_column calls on these dependent models. For instance, I had to rename the 'merchant_id' column to 'business_id' in various join tables (for has_and_belongs_to_many relationship) and other dependent tables (for normal has_one and has_many relationships). Otherwise I would have ended up with columns like 'business_stat.merchant_id' pointing to 'business.id'. [Here's a good answer about doing column renames.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-can-i-rename-a-database-column-in-a-rails-migration)
- When grepping, remember to search for singular, plural, capitalized,
  lowercase, and even UPPERCASE (which may occur in comments) versions
  of your strings.
- It's best to search for plural versions first, then singular. That
  way if you have an irregular plural - such as in my merchants ::
  businesses example - you can get all the irregular plurals correct.
  Otherwise you may end up with, for example, 'businesss' (3 s's) as an
  intermediate state, resulting in yet more search-and-replace.
- Don't blindly replace every occurrence. If your model names collide
  with common programming terms, with values in other models, or with
  textual content in your views, you may end up being too over-eager.
  In my example, I wanted to change my model name to 'Business' but
  still refer to them as 'merchants' in the content in my UI. I also had a 'merchant' role for my users in CanCan - it was the confusion between the merchant role and the Merchant model that caused me to rename the model in the first place.

Answer (score 29):

You also need to replace your indexes:

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable< ActiveRecord:Migration
  def self.up
    remove_index :old_table_name, :column_name
    rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
    add_index :new_table_name, :column_name
  end 

  def self.down
    remove_index :new_table_name, :column_name
    rename_table :new_table_name, :old_table_name
    add_index :old_table_name, :column_name
  end
end
```

And rename your files etc, manually as other answers here describe.

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Make sure you can rollback and roll forward after you write this migration. It can get tricky if you get something wrong and get stuck with a migration that tries to effect something that no longer exists. Best trash the whole database and start again if you can't roll back. So be aware you might need to back something up.

Also: check schema_db for any relevant column names in other tables defined by a has_ or belongs_to or something. You'll probably need to edit those too.

And finally, doing this without a regression test suite would be nuts.

Comment: As for rails 4.0.0.beta1 migrations, it doesn't necessary to update indexes manually. AR updates it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do
execute this command : rails g migration 
rename_{old_table_name}*to*{new_table_name}

after you edit the file and add this code in the method change

rename_table :{old_table_name}, :{new_table_name}

Answer (score 0):

A more modern and efficient way to do this would be :

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
      end
      dir.down do
        rename_table :new_table_name, :old_table_name
      end
    end
  end
end
```

++ don't forget to rename the model declaration file manually.

---

**Personal experience :**

I tried @readonly's solution to rename my table. I only had to add an 'S' at the end of my table, so the only difference between my old table and my new table was this letter.
And the solution didn't worked. Rails considered this to be the same table and therefore made no changes.
I tried with the modern solution I gave above, and it works normally.

*Rails version : 6.1.7.2*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the name of the `collaboration` table to `comment` in Rails 7, follow these steps:

1. Open your terminal and navigate to your Rails application directory.
2. Run the following command to generate a new migration file:

   `rails generate migration ChangeCollaborationToComment`

   This will generate a new migration file with a name like `timestamp_change_collaboration_to_comment.rb`.
3. Open the generated migration file in the `db/migrate` directory.
4. Update the migration file to use the `rename_table` method:

`class ChangeCollaborationToComment < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0] def change rename_table :collaborations, :comments end end`

This will change the table name from `collaborations` to `comments`.

5. Save the migration file.
6. Run the migration using the following command:

   `rails db:migrate`

   This will apply the changes to your database.

After running the migration, the table name should be updated from `collaborations` to `comments` in your database. Adjust the migration file and table names accordingly based on your actual setup.