# How can I rename a database column in a Ruby on Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rename, alter-table

I wrongly named a column `hased_password` instead of `hashed_password`.

How do I update the database schema, using migration to rename this column?

Answer (score 2504, accepted):

```
rename_column :table, :old_column, :new_column
```

You'll probably want to create a separate migration to do this. (Rename `FixColumnName` as you will.):

```
bin/rails generate migration FixColumnName
# creates  db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxx_fix_column_name.rb
```

Then edit the migration to do your will:

```
# db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxx_fix_column_name.rb
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end

  def self.down
    # rename back if you need or do something else or do nothing
  end
end
```

---

For Rails 3.1 use:

While, the `up` and `down` methods still apply, Rails 3.1 receives a `change` method that "knows how to migrate your database and reverse it when the migration is rolled back without the need to write a separate down method".

See "[Active Record Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)" for more information.

```
rails g migration FixColumnName

class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end
end
```

If you happen to have a whole bunch of columns to rename, or something that would have required repeating the table name over and over again:

```
rename_column :table_name, :old_column1, :new_column1
rename_column :table_name, :old_column2, :new_column2
...
```

You could use `change_table` to keep things a little neater:

```
class FixColumnNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :table_name do |t|
      t.rename :old_column1, :new_column1
      t.rename :old_column2, :new_column2
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Then just `db:migrate` as usual or however you go about your business.

---

For Rails 4:

While creating a `Migration` for renaming a column, Rails 4 generates a `change` method instead of `up` and `down` as mentioned in the above section. The generated `change` method is:

```
$ > rails g migration ChangeColumnName
```

which will create a migration file similar to:

```
class ChangeColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end
end
```

Comment: self.down should *always* be the opposite of self.up, so "if you need or do something else or do nothing" isn't really recommended.  Just do: 
    rename_column :table_name, :new_column, :old_column

Comment: While it's normal practice to revert what you did in `self.up` I would not say `self.down` "should *always* be opposite". In depends on the context of your migration. Just putting the "opposite" might not be the "right" down migration.

Comment: In Rails 3.1 you can replace `def self.up` and `def self.down` with `def change` and it'll know how to rollback.

Comment: Turadg - *it'll know how to rollback most of the time. I find the `change` method isn't full proof, so tend to use `up` and `down` methods for complex migrations.

Comment: In rails 4, the def change method still applys

Comment: Does renaming remove index?

Comment: @MikeC It does not - the indices are modified as appropriate

Comment: While this is all correct, if your app is of any substantial size you'll need to be aware that Rails caches columns and your app will break until the servers are restarted. You'll may need to do the migration in stages if that doesn't fit into your SLA. Here is a resource on that strategy. https://blog.codeship.com/rails-migrations-zero-downtime/   Also, keep in mind that migrations on large tables can lock the table for unacceptable periods of time. You may need to lean on a library like 'Large Hadron Migrator' to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 72):

In my opinion, in this case, it's better to use `rake db:rollback`, then edit your migration and again run `rake db:migrate`.

However, if you have data in the column you don't want to lose, then use `rename_column`.

Comment: Even on a "team of one", if you have multiple instances of your app running, say in different environments or on multiple computers etc, managing edited migrations is a major pain. I only edit a migration if I *just* created it and realized it was wrong, and haven't run it literally anywhere else yet.

Comment: I had to restart the server after that.

Comment: This technique should only be used in a situation where your changes haven't yet been merged with your production branch, and others aren't dependent on data persistence. In most every production circumstance, this is NOT the preferred method.

Comment: never ever do this kind of things.

Comment: I like to say to my team: 'Migrations are free' 

The cost of editing a migration which has been released into the wild is high: I once spent a few hours working out why my code wasn't working before I realised another team member had gone back and edited a migration which I'd already run.

So don't edit an existing migration, use a new one to change the schema, because...

...'Migrations are free!'

(it's not strictly true, but it makes the point)

Comment: I am once again asking you to never do this once the migration is already in production

Answer (score 37):

If the column is already populated with data and live in production, I'd recommend a step by step approach, so as to avoid downtime in production while waiting for the migrations.

First I'd create a db migration to add columns with the new name(s) and populate them with the values from the old column name.

```
class AddCorrectColumnNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :table, :correct_name_column_one, :string
    add_column :table, :correct_name_column_two, :string

    puts 'Updating correctly named columns'
    execute "UPDATE table_name SET correct_name_column_one = old_name_column_one, correct_name_column_two = old_name_column_two"
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :table, :correct_name_column_one
    remove_column :table, :correct_name_column_two
  end
end
```

Then I'd commit just that change, and push the change into production.

```
git commit -m 'adding columns with correct name'
```

Then once the commit has been pushed into production, I'd run.

```
Production $ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then I'd update all of the views/controllers that referenced the old column name to the new column name.  Run through my test suite, and commit just those changes. (After making sure it was working locally and passing all tests first!)

```
git commit -m 'using correct column name instead of old stinky bad column name'
```

Then I'd push that commit to production.

At this point you can remove the original column without worrying about any sort of downtime associated with the migration itself.

```
class RemoveBadColumnNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    remove_column :table, :old_name_column_one
    remove_column :table, :old_name_column_two
  end

  def down
    add_column :table, :old_name_column_one, :string
    add_column :table, :old_name_column_two, :string
  end
end
```

Then push this latest migration to production and run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` in the background.

I realize this is a bit more involved of a process, but I'd rather do this than have issues with my production migration.

Comment: I like the thinking behind this, and I would +1 your repsonse but that data update would take a very long time to execute since it's going through rails and doing one row at a time. 

The migration would execute much faster with raw sql statements to update correctly named columns.

For example, in the first db migration script, after adding the duplicate column names,

`execute "Update table_name set correct_name_column_one = old_name_column_one"`

Comment: @mr.ruh.roh ^ Totally agree, should have written that in the first place.  I've edited to reflect a single efficient sql statement.  Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: What happens with entries in between moving to the new table and updating the code to use the new table? Could you not have potentially unmigrated data left over?

Comment: while this is a 'safe' answer, I feel it is incomplete. Many people here say don't do this -why? persistence of data. And that is valid.  Probably the least painful way accomplish the goal is to create the new fields, populate them with the data from the old columns, adjust controllers.  If you want to delete the old columns, you'll certainly have to edit the views. The cost of keeping them is extra db space and some duplicate effort in controller. The tradeoffs are thus clear.

Answer (score 28):

See the "Available Transformations" section in the "[Active Record Migrations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html)" documentation.

```
rename_column(table_name, column_name, new_column_name):
```

Renames a column but keeps the type and content.

Comment: See also [documentation for `rename_column`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-rename_column).

Answer (score 21):

Run this command to create a migration file:

```
rails g migration ChangeHasedPasswordToHashedPassword
```

Then in the file generated in the `db/migrate` folder, write `rename_column` as below:

```
class ChangeOldColumnToNewColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
     rename_column :table_name, :hased_password, :hashed_password
  end
end
```

Answer (score 17):

From the API:

```
rename_column(table_name, column_name, new_column_name)
```

This renames a column but keeps the type and content remains the same.

Answer (score 14):

I had this challenge when working on a Rails 6 application with a PostgreSQL database.

Here's how I fixed it:

In my case the `table_name` was "Products", the `old_column` was "SKU" and the `new_column` was "ProductNumber".

1. Create a migration file that will contain the command for renaming the column:

   ```
    rails generate migration RenameSKUToProductNumberInProducts
   ```
2. Open the migration file in the `db/migrate directory`:

   ```
    db/migrate/20201028082344_rename_sku_to_product_number_in_products.rb
   ```
3. Add the command for renaming the column:

   ```
    class RenameSkuToProductNumberInProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
      def change
        # rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
        rename_column :products, :sku, :product_number
      end
    end
   ```
4. Save, and then run the migration command:

   ```
    rails db:migrate
   ```

You can now confirm the renaming of the column by taking a look at the schema file:

```
    db/schema.rb
```

If you are not satisfied with the renaming of the column, you can always rollback:

```
    rails db:rollback
```

*Note*: Endeavour to modify the column name to the new name in all the places where it is called.

Answer (score 12):

If your code is not shared with other one, then best option is to do just `rake db:rollback`
then edit your column name in migration and `rake db:migrate`. Thats it

And you can write another migration to rename the column

```
 def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_name, :new_name
  end
```

Thats it.

Comment: `rake db:rollback` is a great suggestion.  But like you said, only if the migration hasn't been pushed yet.

Answer (score 12):

Some versions of Ruby on Rails support the `up`/`down` methods for migration and if you have an `up`/`down` method in your migration, then:

```
def up
    rename_column :table_name, :column_old_name, :column_new_name
end

def down
    rename_column :table_name, :column_new_name, :column_old_name
end
```

If you have the `change` method in your migration, then:

```
def change
    rename_column :table_name, :column_old_name, :column_new_name
end
```

For more information see: [Ruby on Rails - Migrations](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-migrations.htm) or [Active Record Migrations](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Migration).

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative option, if you are not married to the idea of migrations, there is a compelling gem for ActiveRecord which will handle the name changes automatically for you, Datamapper style. All you do is change the column name in your model, and make sure you put `Model.auto_upgrade!` at the bottom of your model.rb, and viola! The database is updated on the fly.

See https://github.com/DAddYE/mini_record

*Note: You will need to nuke `db/schema.rb` to prevent conflicts.*

It is still in the beta phase and obviously not for everyone, but it is still a compelling choice. I am currently using it in two non-trivial production apps with no issues.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to switch column names you will need to create a placeholder to avoid a "duplicate column name" error. Here's an example:

```
class SwitchColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :column_name, :x, :holder
    rename_column :column_name, :y, :x
    rename_column :column_name, :holder, :y
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

For Ruby on Rails 4:

```
def change
    rename_column :table_name, :column_name_old, :column_name_new
end
```

Comment: In case it saves someone looking it up, `table_name` is plural. E.g. :students

Answer (score 8):

Generate the migration file:

```
rails g migration FixName
```

which creates `db/migrate/xxxxxxxxxx.rb`.

Edit the migration to do your will:

```
class FixName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

If the present data is not important for you, you can just take down your original migration using:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION='YOUR MIGRATION FILE VERSION HERE'
```

Without the quotes, then make changes in the original migration and run the up migration again by:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply create a new migration, and in a block, use `rename_column` as below.

```
rename_column :your_table_name, :hased_password, :hashed_password
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). All it takes is three simple steps. The following works for **Rails 5.2**.

## 1 . Create a Migration

- `rails g migration RenameNameToFullNameInStudents`
- `rails g RenameOldFieldToNewFieldInTableName` - that way it is perfectly clear to maintainers of the code base later on. (use a plural for the table name).

## 2. Edit the migration

`# I prefer to explicitly write the`up`and`down`methods.`

`# ./db/migrate/20190114045137_rename_name_to_full_name_in_students.rb`

```
class RenameNameToFullNameInStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    # rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
    rename_column :students, :name, :full_name
  end

  def down
            # Note that the columns are reversed
    rename_column :students, :full_name, :name
  end
end
```

## 3. Run your migrations

`rake db:migrate`

And you are off to the races!

Answer (score 5):

Manually we can use the below method:

We can edit the migration manually like:

- Open `app/db/migrate/xxxxxxxxx_migration_file.rb`
- Update `hased_password` to `hashed_password`
- Run the below command

  ```
  $> rake db:migrate:down VERSION=xxxxxxxxx
  ```

Then it will remove your migration:

```
$> rake db:migrate:up VERSION=xxxxxxxxx
```

It will add your migration with the updated change.

Comment: it won't be safe as you might loose data - if the column is already live. but can do for new column and/or table.

Answer (score 5):

Run `rails g migration ChangesNameInUsers` (or whatever you would like to name it)

Open the migration file that has just been generated, and add this line in the method (in between `def change` and `end`):

`rename_column :table_name, :the_name_you_want_to_change, :the_new_name`

Save the file, and run `rake db:migrate` in the console

Check out your `schema.db` in order to see if the name has actually changed in the database!

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

```
 def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
  end
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score 4):

**Generate a Ruby on Rails migration**:

```
$:> rails g migration Fixcolumnname
```

**Insert code in the migration file (XXXXXfixcolumnname.rb)**:

```
class Fixcolumnname < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$:  rails g migration RenameHashedPasswordColumn
invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160323054656_rename_hashed_password_column.rb
```

Open that migration file and  modify that file as below(Do enter your original `table_name`)

```
class  RenameHashedPasswordColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :hased_password, :hashed_password
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In the console:

```
rails generate migration newMigration
```

In the newMigration file:

```
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to do this:

1. In this type it automatically runs the reverse code of it, when rollback.

   ```
   def change
     rename_column :table_name, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
   end
   ```
2. To this type, it runs the up method when `rake db:migrate` and runs the down method when `rake db:rollback`:

   ```
   def self.up
     rename_column :table_name, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
   end

   def self.down
     rename_column :table_name,:new_column_name,:old_column_name
   end
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Open your Ruby on Rails console and enter:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.rename_column :tablename, :old_column, :new_column
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm on rails 5.2, and trying to rename a column on a devise User.

the `rename_column` bit worked for me, but the singular `:table_name` threw a "User table not found" error.  Plural worked for me.

```
rails g RenameAgentinUser
```

Then change migration file to this:

```
rename_column :users, :agent?, :agent
```

Where :agent? is the old column name.

Answer (score 1):

A close cousin of `create_table` is `change_table`, used for changing existing tables. It is used in a similar fashion to `create_table` but the object yielded to the block knows more tricks. For example:

```
class ChangeBadColumnNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :your_table_name do |t|
      t.rename :old_column_name, :new_column_name
    end
  end
end
```

This way is more efficient if we use it with other alter methods such as: remove/add index/remove index/add column. We can do things like:

Rename

```
t.rename :old_column_name, :new_column_name
```

Add column

```
t.string :new_column
```

Remove column

```
t.remove :removing_column
```

Index column

```
t.index :indexing_column
```

Comment: Please don't use "edited" or "update" type tags. Instead, incorporate the change as if it had always been there. If we need to know what changed we can look at the edit log.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a migration run the below command to update the column name:

```
rename_column :your_table_name, :hased_password, :hashed_password
```

Also, make sure that you update any usage of the old column name in your code with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate the migration using:

```
rails g migration rename_hased_password
```

After that edit the migration and add the following line in the `change` method:

```
rename_column :table, :hased_password, :hashed_password
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`rails g migration migrationName`

So you go to your generated migration and add:

```
rename_column :table, :old_column, :new_column
```

to the method

Answer (score 0):

First you need to run

```
rails g migration create_new_column_in_tablename new_column:datatype
rails g migration remove_column_in_tablename old_column:datatype
```

and then you need to check db/migration
you can check the details in the nem migration, if all the details is correct you need to run:

```
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: do you need migrate existed data from old_column to new_column ?

Comment: No, you don't need if you want just to rename it.

Answer (score -1):

Rails 5 migration changes

eg:

> rails g model Student student_name:string age:integer

if you want to change **student_name** column as **name**

Note:- if you not run **rails db:migrate**

You can do following steps

> rails d model Student student_name:string age:integer

This will remove generated migration file, Now you can correct your column name

> rails g model Student name:string age:integer

If you migrated(rails db:migrate), following options to change column name

> rails g migration RemoveStudentNameFromStudent student_name:string
>
> rails g migration AddNameToStudent name:string

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `rails g migration RemoveStudentNameFromStudentS student_name:string` (the students are plural)?

Comment: Also this is dangerous: the column is not renamed, but entirely removed and then readded. What will happen to the data? This may not be what the user will want.

Answer (score -1):

Could be a better idea than rename a column, create a new column and copy the content:

with this way we can save the content in the old column

this could be the generation:

```
rails generate migration add_birthdate_to_User birthdate:string
```

this could be the migration:

```
class AddBirthdateToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :user, :birthdate, :json, default: '[]', null: false

    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        User.update_all('birthdate=birtdate') # rubocop:disable Rails/SkipsModelValidations
      end
    end
  end
end
```

after that you have to remove the wrong column 'Birtdate'

```
class RemoveBirthdateFromUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    remove_column :User, :Birtdate, :json
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to do data migrations in the schema migration layer.