# renaming a column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to rename a column using a command like:

```
script/generate migration AddColumnToTable column:type
```

? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename a database column in rails using migration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-to-rename-a-database-column-in-rails-using-migration)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rails does have a migration command on the ActiveRecord ConnectionAdapter called `rename_column`.  You can generate a migration and then write the code yourself.  example (MySQL):

```
script/generate migration rename_my_column_by_hand
```

Then edit the file it creates:

```
class RenameMyColumnByHand < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_column :my_table, :old_name, :new_name
  end

  def self.down
    rename_column :my_table, :new_name, :old_name
  end
end
```

It executes SQL like:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE old_name new_name BIGINT;
```

**Note** This only renames the column, it won't rename any references you have to it on other tables.

Comment: wow this really works, also with sqlite. I always have this problem as I like to use column-names that are reserved in rails, and until now I  used much more complicated approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Great question. The answer is, unfortunately, no. See Rails 2.3.5 source code:

```
lib/rails_generator/generators/components/migration/migration_generator.rb
```

The only keywords that are recognized by the migration generator are `add`, `remove`, and `to`/`from`.

Answer (score 2):

I use a bit of trickery here. Say I want to change column foo to bar.

Create a migration with the following steps

- Add a temporary column temp_foo
- Update all records, saving foo's value in temp_foo
- Add a bar column
- Update all records, saving temp_foo's value in bar
- Drop column foo
- Drop column temp_foo

This is ex-tre-me-ly brittle. If one step fails, you might loose data..