# How to rename fields and make them not nulls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My current schema looks like:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.datetime "loggedin_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  `user_status`
end
```

I want to rename `username` to `user_name`, and make all the fields not null (they are currently nullable).

How would I do this? Do I create a migration file using `rails generate`, and then have to tweak it manually? How so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can help if you specify the Rails version number.

Before 3.0, it is:

[Rails: How can I rename a database column in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1992019/128421)

If it is 3.0 or later, then you can look at the [Migration documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html), such as `rails generate` instead of `script/generate`.