# rails form - checkboxes, FK and datetime -> how to store those attributes in the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

(rails 2.2.2)

I have 2 models, user and subscription. Each user can have one ore more subscriptions (= premium services). Below the attributes:

- user: id, username, ...
- subscription: id, user_id (FK), type, started_at, ended_at

The classes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  has_many :subscriptions, :dependent => :destroy
  ..
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :user_id
end
```

Now I want to make the UI part where existing users can subscribe in their account for the premium services. Therefore I wanted to make a first simple version where the user can subscribe by clicking on a checkbox. This is what I get so far

```
<div class = 'wrapper'>
  <%= render :partial => "my_account_leftbar" %>

  <% form_for @subscription, :url => subscribe_user_path(current_user) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= (f.check_box :type?) %>      <!-- add '?'after the symbol, source: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/269 -->
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe", :class => "button mr8" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Problems:

1. the app inserts a record into the db, but the attribute I defined in the form (type) has not been set (it should set '1' which stands for 'standard subscription') . How to get the app set this attribute?
2. how to set the FK? I assume that rails should set the FK automatically, is that assumption correct?
3. how to set the other values 'started_at' and 'ended_at? Those are datetime(timestamp) values...

Just run out of my beginner rails knowledge, any help really appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Type' is a ruby on rails reserved word which should only be used when you are using Single Table Inheritance. You should rename your column name to something else.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I also managed to get the other attributes saved.

Answer (score 2):

I could solve the other questions 2 and 3 as well, wrapping it up:

1. insert the record: as stated in the answer from Wahaj, renaming the column 'type' into e.g. 'subscription_type' helped. I created a seperate migration as described here: [How can I rename a database column in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-to-rename-a-database-column-in-rails-using-migration)
2. storing the FK: updated the action in the controller. Instead of just writing

   @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])

   I wrote the following method to create a 'user's subscription'

   @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build(params[:subscription])
3. storing the 'started_at': added a method to the controller:

   @subscription.update_attributes(:started_at => Time.zone.now)