# Rails: Editing Model Column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm not sure why it happened, but one of the columns starts with a capital letter. I'm a little worried to change it by doing migrations because the affected column is 'comment_id' column, and Comment is this model's parent.

```
 id | has_voted | Comment_id | created_at | updated_at
----+-----------+------------+------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

this belongs to comment model. Is it okay to drop Comment_id and simply adding comment_id column by generating new migrations? Or should I fix it somewhere else?

Comment: If you drop the column, the data in it will be lost (unless you copy it first).

Comment: It's okay since I don't have any data yet. So would it be okay to drop it and add the correct column in this case?

Comment: Or you could just rename the column: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html. I'm not sure how it will work in this case. Are column names case-sensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a new migration file:

```
  rails g migration FixColumnName
```

Now, edit the file `../migrate/fix_column_name.rb` and change the `table_name` for the real name of your table.

```
  class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    rename_column :table_name, :Comment_id, :comment_id
    end
  end
```

source: [How can I rename a database column in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-can-i-rename-a-database-column-in-a-rails-migration)