# Rails migration to remove field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Hello I am about to attempt to run a rails migration on a database of skills that has a :title and :description.  I need to remove the description field and I assume it will look something like this:

```
rails migration remove_column :skills, :description
```

I am running it by you pros before I attempt it and end up breaking something on accident.  Please let me know if I have the right idea about removing the description field from the database.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `skills` is the name of your table and `description` is the name of the column you want to remove, you can type `rails g migration RemoveDescriptionFromSkills` in your terminal. This will generate a migration file with the name `[timestamp]_remove_description_from_skills.rb`, located in `db/migrate`. Edit this file so that it contains the following:

```
class RemoveDescriptionFromSkills < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :skills, :description
  end
end
```

Then type `rake db:migrate` in your terminal, and the column will be removed.

For more information, check out this helpful Stack Overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1992045/3723769.

Note: this answer is intended to describe how to perform the migration. As a safety measure, you should do what Michael Durrant advises before migrating: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25006727/3723769.

Comment: Thanks so much! rails makes back end tasks so easy sometimes=D Thanks again Stefan!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some of the things that some to mind:-

- check the existing values to see if there's any data you want
- see if any indexes exist that should also be dropped.
- search the application for that field name
- see if there's an existing rails migration that you can use to DOWN the change

Finally, I would consider creating a `change` migration as normal, i.e. one that actaully adds the field and then I would run it using the down syntax to remove the field.