# Update manual database changes in rails app

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I created **'Country'** table with following columns in rails:

> **Country**       
>    id           
>    country_code 
>    name
>    prefix
>    url

Then, updated column names in **phppgadmin** and now table looks like:

> **Country**       
>    id           
>    country_id   
>    country_name
>    country_iso
>    url

But, in rails i have **schema** still as:

> create_table "countries", force: true do |t|
>      t.integer  "country_code"
>      t.string   "name"
>      t.string   "prefix"
>      t.string   "url"
>      t.datetime "created_at"
>      t.datetime "updated_at"
>    end

How to update the changes made from **phppgadmin** to my rails app.

PS: I am beginner in rails. Please help me if i am following any wrong approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can rebuild the schema with `bin/rake db:schema:dump`, *but back up for a minute* before you just do that.

if you want changes to your database structure, don't do this with some other tool, but instead make a [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). here's a stackoverflow article on how to rename columns using a migration: [How can I rename a database column in a Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-can-i-rename-a-database-column-in-a-rails-migration) (use the rails 3.1 version in the linked stackoverflow question, it's still valid for rails 4+)

Answer (score 0):

You can always rename column name by using migrations and that would also be the best practice (correct me if I am wrong).

Create a migration file

```
rails g migration RenameColumnNameTableName
```

It will generate a migration file

> "#{current_timestamp}_rename_column_name_table_name.rb"

Write migration for change column name

```
class RenameColumnNameTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column_name, :new_column_name
  end
end
```

Run `rake db:migrate` and you will notice change in your schema file.