# (Rails) How should I decide a migration class's name which has `rename_column`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sometimes I name unfavorable column name in its model.

And I want to rename column with `rename_column` method, like below.

```
class XXX
  rename_column :users, :user_name, :name
end
```

But I'm not sure how I can give the class name for this migration.

Is there any usual way to name it?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with `class ChangeUsernameToName`

Comment: I feel that's nice in this case.
But If there is the same column name on other models, the name seems to be unclear.

Comment: Then go with `class ChangeUsersUsernameToName`

Comment: Check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-can-i-rename-a-database-column-in-a-rails-migration

Comment: I agree with @XMLSlayer 's solution.
`class ChangeUsersUsernameToName` looks better.
Thanks!