# rails migration and renaming blob column (sqlite)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite, rails-migrations

created a new rails db migration for renaming a set of columns including one with blob format. when running the migration the following error occurs and the migration is canceled:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token: "'Salted__��v�/JB���*}�]��+Ai��x��w=9yǚ�...
```

the migration:

```
...
rename_column :users, :private_key, :encrypted_private_key
...
```

as far as I know when a column is renamed, there is a temporary table created. to me it looks like there's a problem when creating this temporary table.

is there any way to rename a blob column ?

Rails 4.2.0, Activerecord 4.2.0

Comment: Instead of AR handling the migration.. in your migration file put this in your up method: execute "alter table users change private_key encrypted_private_key varchar(255)"

Answer (score 0):

Check this link explained well

[Renaming column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-can-i-rename-a-database-column-in-a-rails-migration)

In case, if you need change format of table:

```
rails g migration ChangeFormatInTablenameColumnname

class ChangeFormatInUsersAdmin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users(tablename), :admin(columnname), :boolean(type), default: false
  end
end
```

Comment: thx for the link but it doesn't explain how to handle blob fields. As described in my post it's clear to me how to write a migration for renaming a column.