# UnknownAttributeError in ContactsController#create

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, attributes

This error is coming up after pressing submit on my form saving to db as I'm taking a course in Ruby. I have also already attempted `rake:db` migrate to no avail.

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ContactsController#create
unknown attribute: comments
```

Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

```
if @contact.save
  redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
```

### my contact controler.rb code

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

 def new
 @contact = Contact.new
 end

 def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @contact.save
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
    else
      redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occurred."
    end
 end

 private
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
end
```

---

My contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    def name
    end

    def email
    end

    def comments
    end

end

--------------

    class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :commments

      t.timestamps
    end
 end
end
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your migration file the column comments has 3m's (:commments) instead of two

```
def change 
     create_table :contacts do |t| 
             t.string :name 
             t.string :email 
             t.text :commments

             t.timestamps
end
```

Now you have to change the column by creating a migration
[How can I rename a database column in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-can-i-rename-a-database-column-in-a-ruby-on-rails-migration)

Comment: Thanks i was able to get it working this method as the data was not important at this time  "in this case, better use rake db:rollback. Then edit your migration and again type rake db:migrate. However, if you have data in the column you don't want to lose, then use rename_column."

Comment: db:rollback is good , if you dont have any important data .glad it worked for you , best of luck with your app ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is `:comments` a db field in your `Contact` model? It should be for it to work in here:

```
def 
    contact_params params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments) 
end
```

Comment: thanks model appears as:

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    
    def name
    end
    
    def email
    end
    
    def comments
    end
    
end