# Railscasts: authentication from scratch - missing :session param issue in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, railscasts

I'm working through *Railscast: authentication from scratch* in Rails 4, though the tutorial was built for Rails 3.
For this reason, some changes have had to be made from the original tutorial instructions.

Tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?autoplay=true

**Current running into an error**

> param is missing or the value is empty: session

**Thoughts:**

- I've compared the 2 controllers below. My change from the tutorial is moving the params into a session_params method.
- I understand the error is because the hash being posted does not contain a hash like `"session" => { }`. But I don't have a deep enough understanding of Rails to solve.

**Recommended controller (rails 3)**

```
def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
  if user
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
  else
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
  end
end
```

**My controller (converted to Rails 4)**

```
  def create
    user = User.authenticate(session_params)
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private
  def session_params
    params.require(:session).permit(:email, :password)
  end
```

Up to this point I've only been using Devise for authentication, so a great thanks in advance if you can share any advice.

**UPDATE**

As requested, form to post session

```
<h1>Log in</h1>
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
    <p>
        <%= label_tag :email %> <br/>
        <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= label_tag :password %> <br/>
        <%= password_field_tag :password %>
    </p>
    <p class="button"> <%= submit_tag %> </p>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Also adding user.rb model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
    before_save :encrypt_password

    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

    def self.authenticate(email, password)
        user = find_by_email(email)
        if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
            user
        end
    end

    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
            self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: can u post your form_for too ? Also, do u use `gem bcrypt` ?

Comment: Added the form, though per the tutorial i'm using a form_tag. Yes - i am using bcrypt.

Comment: you do not need `resources :sessions` in routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

in **sessions_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        flash[:success] = "#{@user.email}, Successfully Logged In"
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged in!"
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = "Incorrect User/Password"
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

**html form**

```
<%= form_for :session, url: :sessions do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit "Sign In", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
post 'sessions'  => 'sessions#create'
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password

    validates_confirmation_of :password
    validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_uniqueness_of :email

end
```

Comment: Getting an error `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)`, related to `def self.authenticate(email, password)` method in user.rb

Comment: where is that `self.authenticate` method located ?

Comment: user.rb - added above.

Comment: @pandaman i see, comment all methods there, `authenticate  and encrypt_passwrd` and add this one there `has_secure_password`, do not forget to add `gem 'bcrypt'`. bundle and restart server.

Comment: bcrypt gem supports authenticate and encryption methods.

Comment: `bcrypt` is already installed. So if i comment `authenticate` and `encrypt_password`, and change `@user.authenticate` to `User.has_secure_password`, then it errors `undefined method fetch for "password_name":String`

Comment: still getting `undefined method fetch` error related to this line `if @user && User.has_secure_password(params[:session][:password])`. And if use `@user...` instead of `User...`, i get an undefined method `has_secure_password`.

Comment: I am sorry, where is your `has_secure_password` method ?

Comment: Sorry, if i do exactly like `@user.authenticate...`, i get the error, `undefined local variable or method "password_digest" for #<User:0x007f33e425d928> Did you mean? password_salt`

Comment: ohhh, how is your password column named in users table ? if its just password then u need to rename column name to `password_digest `

Comment: here is example, how to rename column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-can-i-rename-a-database-column-in-a-ruby-on-rails-migration