# How to change column in database in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going into my ruby console with

```
ruby c
```

Then I type in

```
rename_column :table_name :old_column :new_column
```

where table_name old_column and new_column is replaced with the correct attributes

After I click enter, I receive the following error:

```
    SyntaxError ((irb):1: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting end-of-input)
rename_column :table_name ^:old_column :new_column
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a migration for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rename a database column in a Ruby on Rails migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992019/how-can-i-rename-a-database-column-in-a-ruby-on-rails-migration)

Comment: As pointed out your format is not correct for a ruby command, but even with a correct format there is no `main:Object` method `rename_column`.  You can't do that in the console.  See Jay Dorsey's answer for how to do this change.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate a migration.

```
rails generate migration ChangeColumnFoo
```

Open the file in `db/migrate` folder that it says was created.

Add a new line after the `def change` line and add your rename:

```
rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
```

Save the file then run `rake db:migrate` from the console.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some commas:

Original:

```
rename_column :table_name :old_column :new_column
```

Edited:

```
rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the commas :

```
rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
```