# Renaming table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to rename a table... (any table.)

I tried this line of code:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements.rename_table(old_name, new_name)
```

Here's the weird thing.  I know I got it working the first time, but now I get this error: undefined method `rename_table' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements:Module

Was there something I need to set?

Answer (score 250, accepted):

You would typically do this sort of thing in a migration:

```
class RenameFoo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :foo, :bar
  end

  def self.down
    rename_table :bar, :foo
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!  I'm still puzzled why the previous line didn't though.  Oh well..

Comment: @Tommy, the `rename_table` method is defined in the `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements`.  It is meant to be mixed in to other modules.  If you wanted to run it directly, I think you could do `include ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements; rename_table :foo, :bar`

Comment: or you could use ActiveRecord::Migration.rename_table(:foo,:bar) if you were so inclined. But migration works best. Would you also want to change the name of the model or want to retain the model name as the old one? If so you may want to specify the table name in the ActiveRecord model using "set_table_name :bar".

Comment: You can also use the new form for migrations with the 'change' method instead of up & down. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/471425/21087)

Comment: def change, not def self.up / def.self.down in modern Rails implementations. Doing the latter will fail silently.

Answer (score 303):

Remember that in Rails >= 3.1 you can use the `change` method.

```
 class RenameOldTableToNewTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
   end 
 end
```

Comment: This will also migrate any indexes from `:old_table_name` to `:new_table_name`

Comment: Just a little comment: 
Perhaps change to :old_named_things, :new_named_things to remind people that table names in activerecord are generally pluralised.

Answer (score 24):

`.rename_table` is an instance method, not a class method, so calling `Class.method` isn't going to work. Instead you'll have to create an instance of the class, and call the method on the instance, like this: `Class.new.method`.

[EDIT]
In this instance, `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements` isn't even a class (as pointed out by cam), which means that you can't even create an instance of it as per what I said above. And even if you used cam's example of `class Foo; include ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements; def bar; rename_table; end; end;`, it still wouldn't work as `rename_table` raises an exception.

On the other hand, `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter` *is* a class, and it is likely this class you'd have to use to rename your table (or SQLite or PostgreSQL, depending on what database you're using). Now, as it happens, `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter` is already accessible through `Model.connection`, so you should be completely able to do `Model.connection.rename_table`, using any model in your application.
[/EDIT]

However, if you wish to permanently rename a table, I would suggest using a migration to do it. It's easy and the preferred way of manipulating your database structure with Rails. Here's how to do it:

```
# Commandline
rails generate migration rename_my_table

# In db/migrate/[timestamp]_rename_my_table.rb:
class RenameMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :my_table, :my_new_table
  end

  def self.down
    rename_table :my_new_table, :my_table
  end
end
```

Then, you can run your migration with `rake db:migrate` (which calls the `self.up` method), and use `rake db:rollback` (which calls `self.down`) to undo the migration.

Comment: I agree that `rename_table` is an instance method, but it is not defined in a class, so your suggestion to call `Class.new.method` won't work (for example: `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements.new` gives the error `oMethodError: undefined method `new' for ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements:Module`

Comment: Also worth pointing out, that if you have a model associated with the table you are renaming, running ```rake db:migrate``` or ```rake db:rollback``` will not rename the model.rb file.  You will need to manually change the model.rb file.

Comment: In newer Rails versions (e.g. 5.x) you can use a **change** method instead of _self.up_ and _self.down_, because Rails can perform a rollback by this, too. So just this code is enough:
`def change`
`rename_table :my_table, :my_new_table`
`end`
. . . . . By the way: Inside of `change` you an use these commands: `add_column`, `add_index`, `add_timestamps`, `create_table`, `remove_timestamps`, `rename_column`, `rename_index`, `rename_table`

Answer (score 4):

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.rename_table(:old_table_name, :new_table_name)
```