# Join table for has_many through in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model, join

I am new to programming & rails and there's something I dont fully understand.
I am creating an app with

```
product has_many categories
category has_many products
```

If I understand correctly I need to create a join table products_categories which has a `product_id` & a `category_id`. First do I also need a model for this table ? if yes I guess it would look like this :

```
class CategoryProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
   belongs_to :product
end
```

and the other models in product.rb :

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_products
  has_many :categories, through: :category_product
  has_attached_file :picture,
    styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }

  validates_attachment_content_type :picture,
    content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
  validates :price,               presence: { message: "Merci d'indiquer le prix du produit" }
  validates :name,                presence: { message: "Merci d'indiquer le nom du produit" }
  validates :weight,              presence: { message: "Merci d'indiquer le poids du produit" }
  validates :description,         presence: { message: "Merci d'écrire une description du produit " }
end
```

and in category.rb

```
    class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_products
  has_many :products,         through: :category_product
  validates :name,                presence: { message: "Merci d'indiquer le nom de la catégorie" }
end
```

Now let's say I want to create a product and while I am creating it, specify as many categories as I want for this product from the categories' list.

So far this was my Product/new.html.slim in my views :

```
  div class="container marged-top"
    div class= "col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-5 bigmarge"
      div class="panel panel-default"
        div class= "panel-heading"
          h4 Création Produit
        div class= "panel-body"
          =simple_form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |t|
            = t.error_notification
            = t.input :name, label: 'Nom'
            = t.input :description, label: 'Description', required: true
            = t.input :price, label: 'Prix', required: true
            = t.input :weight, label: 'Poids', required: true
            = t.label :picture
            = t.file_field :picture
            = t.association :categories, as: :check_boxes
            = t.button :submit, value: "Valider",  class: "btn-success marge-bas"
```

This was a simple form for my Product instance. I guess I need to have a form for a CategoryProduct now ?
How do I have to change that if I want the user to be able to add as many categories he wants to the product while he's creating it ?

Here's my migration file for category_product table :

class CreateTableCategoriesProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration

```
  def change
    create_table :categories_products do |t|
      t.references :product, index: true
      t.references :category, index: true
    end
    add_foreign_key :categories_products, :categories
    add_foreign_key :categories_products, :products
  end
end
```

I renamed the previous table with the following migration file :

```
class RenameTableCategoriesProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    rename_table :categories_products, :category_products
  end

 def self.down
    rename_table :category_products, :categories_products
 end
end
```

I am getting the following error on the simple_form in product/new.html.slim :

```
undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass
```

The code breaks here :

```
 = t.association :categories, as: :check_boxes
```

so I guess my associations arent still quite right

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Rails there are two ways to do many-to-many relationships:

#### has_and_belongs_to_many

sets up a many to many relationship without an intervening model.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

This is a good choice if you know that you will not need to store any additional data about the relationship or add any additional functionality - which in practice is actually really rare. It uses less memory since it does not have to instantiate an extra model just to do `product.category`.

When using `has_and_belongs_to_many` the convention is that the join table is named after the two entities in plural.

```
Category + Product = products_categories
```

The order does not seem to matter.

### has_many through:

as you already have guessed uses an intermediate model.

```
class CategoryProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_products
  has_many :products, through: :category_products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_products
  has_many :categories, through: :category_products
end
```

The advantage here is that you can store and retrieve additional data in the join table which describes the relationship. For example if you wanted to store who added a product to a category - or when the relationship was created.

In order to for Rails to be able to correctly find the ProductCategory class the `has_many though` the naming convention is:

```
model 1(singular) + model 2(plural) 
Product + Category = category_products
```

This is due to the way that rails infers the model class based on the table name. Using `categories_products` would case rails to look for `Category::CategoriesProduct` as plural words are interpreted as modules. However this is really just a lazy naming convention and there is often a noun which better descibes the relation between A and B (such as `Categorization`).

### Many to Many in forms and controllers.

As IvanSelivanov already mentioned SimpleForm has helper methods for creating selects, checkboxes etc.

- https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

But instead of overriding the `.to_s` method in your model you may want to use the label_method option instead.

```
f.assocation :categories, as: :checkboxes, label_method: :name
```

Overriding `.to_s` can make debugging harder and in some cases give confusing test error messages.

To whitelist the params in your controller you would do:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      redirect_to @product
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def product_params
     params.require(:product)
           .permit(:name, :categories_ids, ...)
  end
end
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631630/renaming-table-in-rails for how to fix the table name of your join table.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am know getting an error on my simple_form for product.  The code breaks with the simple_form when hitting the line : = t.association :categories, as: :check_boxes. Could it be because of the way I named my table in my migration file : `:categories_products` which should be `category_products`if I follow you

Comment: NP, yes I'm guessing that's the problem. But a good tip is to be a bit more specific than just "getting an error" - it's a lot easier to help if you include the error message.

Comment: nope event after changing table name I still get `undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass` in my simple_form at line 16 ` = t.association :categories, as: :check_boxes`

Comment: What does adding `debug @product.categories` give you?

Comment: I get `>> @product.categories
!! #<ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :category_product in model Product>`

Comment: but I do have the association in my product.rb :
`class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_products
  has_many :categories, through: :category_product`

Comment: It should be `has_many :categories, through: :category_products`. The `through:` option should match the name of the assocation you are going through.

Answer (score 2):

You also have to add CategoryProduct to each model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :category_products
  has_many :categories, through: :category_product
```

It is very simple using gem `simple form`. All you have to do is to add:

```
t.association :categories
```

in a form for product and add `:category_ids => []` to a list of permitted parameters in your products controller

If you prefer checkboxes instead of multi-select list, you can do

```
    t.association :categories, as: check_boxes
```

And the last thing, to display categories in human-readable format, you need to define a `to_s` method in your category model, i. e.:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_s
    name
  end 
end
```

Comment: I did as you said but when I add t.association :category to my product/new.html.slim form; I get the following error : Association :category not found

Comment: `t.association :categories`

Comment: @max now I get undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @IvanSelivanov I also don't understand why in your associations you writte `has_many :category_products`, why not `:categories_products`?

Comment: @Dave It's because I think this is the right plural form for CategoryProduct. Did you change `has_and_belongs_to_many` to `has_many`? It woud be easier to tell what your errors mean if you post corresponding code (there's usually a line number in the error message)

Comment: I did as you say but I think it is also correct with `has_and_belongs_to_many right` ? I still get `undefined method `klass'`though

Comment: @IvanSelivanov the code breaks with the  simple_form when hitting the line of code you adviced me to add : `= t.association :categories, as: :check_boxes`

Comment: @Dave I just don't use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. I guess it does not matter what you use, but I'm not sure. Can you add a full code of your product model to your question?

Comment: @IvanSelivanov just did it