# Rails 5: rename table migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best possible way to change name of table using migration and change name of all the files like controller, model and associations?

Will there be any issue when someone will try to run `rails:db:migrate` after cloning my repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename rails controller and model in a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924124/how-to-rename-rails-controller-and-model-in-a-project)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

> What is the best possible way to change name of table using migration

To change the name of a table, you can run:

```
$ rails g migration change_[old_table_name]_to_[new_table_name]
```

Within the `change` method in the migration file generated, add this:

```
def change
  rename_table :[old_table_name], :[new_table_name]
end
```

Change `[old_table_name]` and `[new_table_name]` in both cases.

(This part of the question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4631630/2241124).)

> will there be any issue when someone will try to run rails db:migrate after cloning my repo?

Nope. Keep the old migration files in place and generate a new one. That's the benefit of database migrations.

> What is the best possible way to change name of all the files like controller, model and associations?

It's generally not too big of a deal to change a model name. Many text editors have the ability to search and replace within a directory.

And I would manually rename the filenames.

---

[Here's a set of more detailed steps to make sure you've hit everything that needs to be changed.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924254/2241124)

Comment: While searching to replace, remember that case-sensitivity and pluralization will factor in.

Comment: I would also recommend changing your foreign key names in the migration if it applies