# Rails - changed a table name, now tests won't run

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing

Using Rails 3, I've changed the name of a table in the model like this:

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "items"
end
```

But when I try setting up tests, I get the following error:

```
Started
E
Finished in 0.027396 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_the_truth(CustomerTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'project2_test.products' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM `products`


1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
```

Any idea how I can let it know about Products?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you write a migration to rename a Model and its table in Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471416/how-do-you-write-a-migration-to-rename-a-model-and-its-table-in-rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK found the answer here:

http://www.missiondata.com/blog/systems-integration/80/rails-fixtures-with-models-using-set_table_name/

Had to change the name of the Fixture yml file from Products to Items.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than alter the class directly, you should [create a migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).  This will allow Rails to smoothly change the database, and allow any others working on the project to change their database in the same manner.

Write a `change` method which uses `rename_table`.

```
class RenameProductsToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :items, :products :string
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - the reason it's like this is that we are re-building an App, and it has to run at the same time on the same db as the old one until we migrate over.