# Unpermitted parameter with has_many_and_belongs_to :param, through :param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble inputting data into my new model.

I created a new model so I can assign Users to Affiliates.

I have a Users, Affiliates, and UserAffiliates model.

**UserAffiliates**:

```
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :affiliates
```

**User**:

```
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user_affiliate
  has_and_belongs_to_many :affiliate, through: :user_affiliate, optional: true
```

**Affiliate**:

```
  has_many :user_affiliates
  has_many :users, through: :user_affiliates
```

How it works, is an affiliate can have many users, but a user will ever only have one affiliate.  I then have a commission column within the UserAffiliates table to set the commission based on a user by user basis.

I created this form, and it doesn't seem to be working (which is stemmed from a `<% @users.each do |user| %>` that goes through each user in a table:

```
<%= form_for user, remote: true do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :user_affiliates,  remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :affiliate_id, class: "form-control"  %>
  <%= f.submit "Add Affiliate", data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "btn btn-light" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**I get this error:**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"user_affiliates"=>{"affiliate_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Add Affiliate", "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 62ms (ActiveRecord: 6.4ms)



ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:88:in `[]'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:88:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:61:in `block in update'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:60:in `update'
```

**User controller params**:

```
 def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :approved, :seller, :buyer, :admin, :stripe_account, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role, :affiliate_id, :affiliate_ids [], :user_affiliates, :commission)
 end
```

Is my form wrong?

I want to be able to list users in a table as a user.admin, have a text field, and enter an affiliate_id, and then have the user_id and affiliate_id inputted into the UserAffiliate table.  I also want to be able to add commission rates that both the user.admin and Affiliate can change.

How can I do this correctly?

**Update:**

**I fixed my params but still have errors:**

**params:**

```
def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:name, :approved, :seller, :buyer, :admin, :stripe_account, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role, :affiliate_id, :user_affiliates, :affiliate, :commission, affiliate_ids: [])
end
```

**Error:**

```
Started PATCH "/users/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-10 21:20:53 -0500
Processing by UsersController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"user_affiliates"=>{"affiliate_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Add Affiliate", "id"=>"2"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:58
Unpermitted parameter: :user_affiliates
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:61
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:61
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)



ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:60:in `update'
```

I tried changing it to user_affiliate (non pluar) and plural in all the controller, model, and form. Is there anything i need to do to my update on the users controller?

User Controller update:

```
  def update
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   # @affiliate = current_affiliate
   respond_to do |format|
     if @user.update(user_params) # <- you'll need to define these somewhere as well
       if @user.admin?
         format.html { redirect_to '/admin/users', notice: "yahoo" }
         format.json { render json: @user }
       # elsif @affiliate
       #     format.html { redirect_to '/a/clients', notice: "yahoo" }
       #     format.json { render json: @user }
       else
         format.html { render :edit }
         format.json { render json: { errors: @user.errors }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end
```

Comment: Post your controller update method codes.

Comment: posted at bottom @leiliu

Comment: you need a format.js block on you response, since you user remote: true on your form.

Comment: Really, because before i had created the UserAffiliates model to do it this way, I was using the same remote form but with hving the affiliate_id within the users table- just figured this way is more scalable

Comment: Is this is a simple add " respond_to do |format|
    format.js " to my update method?

Comment: I'm not sure if thats the issue.  Any other thoughts or anyone else?

Comment: If you want to add nested attributes for UserAffiliates you need to use [`accepts_nested_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and [`fields_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).

Comment: I have the fields_for and tried with nested attributes but i still get errors about the params like : Unpermitted parameter: :user_affiliate.... is my form wrong?