# How to change a table name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am new to Rails. Facing issue while changing table name.

I tried changing the name by going to `create_table` migration file and changed name from there but it didn't work.

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/471425/13841038

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you write a migration to rename an ActiveRecord model and its table in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471416/how-do-you-write-a-migration-to-rename-an-activerecord-model-and-its-table-in-ra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new migration file for changing the table name and use `rename_table` command like this:

```
rename_table :old_name, :new_name
```

Answer (score 6):

First you need to generate migration for renaming

```
$ rails g migration RenameOldTableToNewTable
```

Then inside the newly created migration file you should add `rename_table` statement

```
class RenameOldTableToNewTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    rename_table :old_table_name, :new_table_name
  end 
end
```

Finally run migrations

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/471425/13841038